# How to extract elements between mulitple curly braces

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a `Regex` on Java for extracting the elements between double curly braces

Example :

```
I am very much new to java...{{envelope|func"{{aa}}{{ds}}|{{abc.xyz}}"}} and i want to know.... more.
```

I tried this regex but it doesn't return the first element full

```
{\{(.*?)(?:\{\{(.*?)\}\})*\}\}
```

I want to extract as the following :

- envelope|func"{{aa}}{{ds}}|{{abc.xyz}}"
- aa
- ds
- abc.xyz

Comment: My usual advise: sometimes one has to decide if a regex is a good solution; or if one better writes a bit of own parsing logic. Typically: when I need to ask others to create that regex for me, I tend to not use regexes. Because I might have a hard time in the future to maintain that thing that I couldnt write down in the first place. And beyond that: I am not even sure if you could write a regex for arbitrary depth brace nesting.

Comment: FYI: Java regex engine does not support recursion, you cannot use regex to match nested balanced substrings. You need to write your own parsing code.

Comment: @Jason4Ever: [Does this work for you?](https://regex101.com/r/JpiHYi/3)

Comment: @anubhava , I've modified my whole code to parse it on another way .. However , your regex is working very well .. but i have to append the last }} ..
Kindly post it as An answer to be useful for all :) .. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer. This is assuming between `{{` and `}}` we have all non-whitespace characters.

This regex is based on lookahead and alternation inside the lookahead. Captured groups are part of lookahead itself.

```
\{\{(?=((?:(?!\{\{|}})\S)*+|\S*)}})
```

Or in Java:

```
final String regex = "\\{\\{(?=((?:(?!\\{\\{|\\}})\\S)*+|\\S*)\\}})";
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpiHYi/4)